# How do I limit number of characters in the admin form in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have following code in my Form.php

```
$fieldset->addField('desc', 'textarea', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Description'),
          'required'  => true,       
          'name'      => 'desc',
      ));
```

How to restrict the number of characters in this text area?

Answer (score 11):

In theory you should be able to do that by adding to the textarea a `maxlength` attribute.
So you should end up with something like this:

```
<textarea maxlength="50"></textarea>
```

But Magento does not allow the `maxlength` attribute.
If you take a look at the `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Textarea` class (the one responsable for rendering textareas) you will see this method.

```
public function getHtmlAttributes()
{
    return array('title', 'class', 'style', 'onclick', 'onchange', 'rows', 'cols', 'readonly', 'disabled', 'onkeyup', 'tabindex');
}
```

Those are the only ones that you can specify when you create the element.

First option would be to extend this class and add the `maxlength` among the allowed attributes, then your column could look like this:

```
$fieldset->addField('desc', 'textarea', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Description'),
      'required'  => true,       
      'name'      => 'desc',
      'maxlength' => 50
));
```

The second option is to add it via some javascript.

```
   $fieldset->addField('desc', 'textarea', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Description'),
      'required'  => true,       
      'name'      => 'desc',
      'after_element_html' => '<script type="text/javascript">Event.observe(window, "load", function() {$("id_of_textarea_here").setAttribute("maxlength", 50)})</script>'
  ));
```

A third option would be to insert instead of the javascript above some code that limits the length of the text.
You can find an [example here](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html).

Final Note:
the content from `after_element_html` will be displayed in the form right after the element. So you can basically put anything there.

Comment: Thanks for that ! 2nd option seems better!

Comment: Works great, thanks. But I noticed that for some fields (for example Category fields), the *after_element_html* attribute is not available, so I had to use the *note* one instead: `$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_category', 'description', 'note', '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("group_7description").setAttribute("maxlength", "200")</script>');`

Comment: @LouisBataillard. Even if that might work it's kind of risky. The note you set is saved in the db. Also the group id might change from installation to installation.  In this case I think a better approach would be to change the fronetend model of the field and make it use after_element_html. But it requires a lot of work.

Comment: @marius At least in Magento 1.9.x and 1.14x `maxlength` is now an allowed attribute in `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Text`